# Elastic Search Bulk is ignoring the last operation provided in the json

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform a **Bulk Operation** in elastic search. However the **last operation** given in the JSON is never executed by elastic search.

This is my **Request**:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/customer/external/_bulk?pretty&pretty' -d'

{"update":{"_id":"1"}}
{"doc": { "name": "Update - John Doe becomes Jane Doe" } }

{"delete":{"_id":"4"}}

{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"name": "Create or Update - New Jane Doe" }

{"create":{"_id":"4"}}
{"name": "Only Create - New Jane Doe" }

{"create":{"_id":"5"}}
{"name": "Only Create - New Jane Doe 1" }'
```

The **Response** Contains just 4 Outputs instead of 5 :

```
{
  "took": 100,
  "errors": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "update": {
        "_index": "customer",
        "_type": "external",
        "_id": "1",
        "_version": 9,
        "result": "noop",
        "_shards": {
          "total": 2,
          "successful": 1,
          "failed": 0
        },
        "status": 200
      }
    },
    {
      "delete": {
        "found": true,
        "_index": "customer",
        "_type": "external",
        "_id": "4",
        "_version": 4,
        "result": "deleted",
        "_shards": {
          "total": 2,
          "successful": 1,
          "failed": 0
        },
        "status": 200
      }
    },
    {
      "index": {
        "_index": "customer",
        "_type": "external",
        "_id": "3",
        "_version": 7,
        "result": "updated",
        "_shards": {
          "total": 2,
          "successful": 1,
          "failed": 0
        },
        "created": false,
        "status": 200
      }
    },
    {
      "create": {
        "_index": "customer",
        "_type": "external",
        "_id": "4",
        "_version": 5,
        "result": "created",
        "_shards": {
          "total": 2,
          "successful": 1,
          "failed": 0
        },
        "created": true,
        "status": 201
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In my scenario, **the customer with id "5" (name: "Only Create - New Jane Doe 1") was never created**. If I remove this last request (id:5) then even id:4 is not getting created.

I did a search to get all documents for customer index, but id:5 was not present.

Its as if Elastic search is ignoring the last part of JSON. I even tried to post the request through PostmanClient and its still the same.

Elastic Search Version : 5.1.1

Comment: I am not sure, try curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/customer/external/_bulk?pretty=true' -d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the JSON must always end with a **new line character** (\n) as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/docs-bulk.html).

I added a new line at the end of JSON and it worked fine.